# The difference between object validation and persistence validation in DDD?

Tags: validation, domain-driven-design

Right now, I have a domain entity named StyleBundle. This StyleBundle takes a list of Styles:

```
public class StyleBundle
{
    public StyleBundle(List<Style> styles)
    {
        this.Styles = styles;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Style> Styles { get; private set;}
}
```

So, in my original design, a StyleBundle should never be created with an empty Style list. This was a rule that the domain experts basically said was good.

I wrote this using a guard clause in the constructor:

```
if (styles.Count() == 0)
   throw new Exception("You must have at least one Style in a StyleBundle.");
```

which made sure I could not create StyleBundle in an invalid state. I thought an exception made sense here b/c a StyleBundle being created without at least one Style was exceptional in the system.

Of course, change came down the road during the rest of the project, and now it should be possible for a user to create a StyleBundle without Styles, but they should not be allowed to PERSIST a StyleBundle without Styles.

So now I'm looking at my guard clause and realizing that I can't have the exception thrown from the constructor anymore.

Moving forward, I have a Service/Application layer that my code-behinds interact with when they're working with StyleBundles. In my Service Layer, I have a StyleBundleService class, and that class exposes basic functionality to the UI... among them is "CreateStyleBundle".

It seems as if I'll have to have my Service Layer check to see if the StyleBundle does or does not have any Styles before it's persisted to the database, but something about this decision feels "wrong" to me.

Anyone run into a similar thing? Basically, the different between the state of an object being valid when "new'ed up" vs. the state of the same object when it comes to persistence?

Thanks!
Mike

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would add an `IsValid` method to your entity. This would check if the entity is currently in a valid state (in your case, check if there are styles).

This method can be called from your `Repository` to check if an entity may be persisted. You can add more rules to the `IsValid` method for specific entities and you can implement something like a collection of Validation errors is you want to throw a meaningful exception.

Comment: is Repositories checking validity of an entity a good or bad idea? Something sounds weird to me about that. But either way, I like the .IsValid idea for my entities. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: I don't think that a latest check in your repository is a bad idea. Otherwise, a user could add some invalid data to the database which wouldn't be caught. Like Momamed Abed suggested, you could split it in a IsValid and IsValidForPersistence method

Answer (score 1):

Expanding what Wouter said, plus handy BeforeSaving and BeforeDeleting methods:

```
public interface IDomainObject<T>
{
    bool IsValid();
}

public interface IEntity<T> : IDomainObject<T>
{

}

public interface IAggregateRoot<T> : IEntity<T>
{
    void BeforeSaving();
    void BeforeDeleting();
}


public interface IAggregateRoot { //or simply IEntity depending on the model
   bool IsValid();
}

public class StyleBundle : IAggregateRoot<T> {
   return styles.Count() > 0
}

public class StyleBundleRepository : Repository<StyleBundle> {
}

public abstract class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class, IAggregateRoot<T> {

   public T Save(T t)
   {
      t.BeforeSaving(); //for all AggregateRoots, maybe logging what the aggregate was like before the changes

      if(!t.IsValid())
         throw Exeception("Entity invalid");

      EntityStore.Current.SaveChanges();         

      // "AfterSaving" here, i.e.: log how the entity looks after the update

   }
}
```

Edit: I dont personally use the IsValid idea, I go with a full class of EntityValidationErrors where I can report back to the client what was wrong before attempting to save, things that shouldnt be null, shouldnt be empty (like your Styles etc)

Comment: do you think Repositories making validity checks against an entity is a good or bad idea though? I'd imagine you want to keep the repository "dumb", and have the service layer call the validate code?

Comment: This makes sure nothing gets persisted as invalid, no matter what the other portions of the code do, and the entity itself is the only one that knows it is invalid, the repository is only reinforcing the contract. I made a couple edits probably after you read it, for further ideas

Comment: F.Aquino, thanks so much for the effort and the code. I'm going to see if I can get something like this into my model over the next couple days. I'll be back to mark accepted answers after that.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple strategies:

Some developers prefer to create 2 methods in the entity itself, one called `IsValid()` which validates the entity in terms of business rules (general validation) and another one called `IsValidForPersistence()` which validates the entity for persistence.

Regarding `IsValid()` I prefer instead not to allow invalid state in the first place by validating all inputs, and to support invariants I use factory or builder.

you may check the link http://www.codethinked.com/thoughts-on-domain-validation-part-1
for some thoughts.

Comment: Mohamed, thanks for the link. That validation implementation is really complex, and I'm sure there are simpler ways to go about implementing .IsValid() and .IsValidForPersistence() on an Aggregate root. I also think using Factory or Builder is a good way to not allow an entity to reach an invalid state, b/c you can still return useful messages to the user/app layer before the entity is constructed. Unless you raise an exception from the entity's constructor, there is no way to report useful info back to the app layer once your in the constructor

Answer (score 0):

I know, this question is three years old, but seeing the current answer is something I like to respond to. We are talking about the domain data. Hence, there can't be a valid StyleBundle with 0 objects. I imagine, you have a frontend editor somewhere, were you create a "new" StyleBundle and have to add at least one style, before hitting the "save" button.

At this point in the frontend, you won't have a domain object. You may have a data transfer object, that will be send with a "CreateNewStyleBundle" command.

In my opinion, the domain object must be agnostic to persitance and should always be in a valid state. If you have to call a "IsValid" method, you circumvent the whole idea of having domain objects in the first place.

That's just my humble opinion.